# Bad request from Soap call to UPNP TV

Tags: c#, soap, upnp, dlna

I've been playing around with sending commands to my Upnp enabled TV.  I've written some C# code to request UPNP devices on the network and then send commands to the tv over soap.  However, when I make requests to the TV I keep getting 400 Bad requests.  I watched in Fiddler and this seems to be the RAW request.

```
POST http://192.168.1.4:52323/upnp/control/RenderingControl HTTP/1.1 SOAPACTION: urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1#SetVolume Content-Type: text/xml;charset="utf-8" Accept: text/xml Host:
192.168.1.4:52323 Content-Length: 418 Expect: 100-continue Connection: Keep-Alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <s:Envelope s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">   <s:Body>
    <ns0:SetVolume xmlns:ns0="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:RenderingControl:1">
      <InstanceId>0</InstanceId>
      <Channel>Master</Channel>
      <DesiredVolume>70</DesiredVolume>
    </ns0:SetVolume>   </s:Body> </s:Envelope>
```

Does anyone see anything bad with this request?

Here is how I'm constructing the WebRequest in C#:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPACTION", action);
webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
webRequest.Method = "POST";
return webRequest;
```

**UPDATED**

I've tried to remove code at all and just form the request through fiddler.  I don't have the television connected to my network at the moment so I'm trying to test calls to my router.  This is my newly constructed call through fiddler:

```
POST http://10.0.0.1:49153/upnp/control/Layer3Forwarding HTTP/1.1
SOAPACTION: urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:Layer3Forwarding:1#GetDefaultConnectionService
Content-Type: text/xml;charset="utf-8"
Host: 10.0.0.1:49153
Content-Length: 345

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <ns0:GetDefaultConnectionService xmlns:ns0="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:Layer3Forwarding:1">
    </ns0:GetDefaultConnectionService>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

However I keep getting either invalid action repsones, or bad xml for example this response below:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
CONTENT-LENGTH: 413
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
DATE: Tue, 14 Mar 2017 21:55:49 GMT
EXT: 
SERVER: Linux/3.12.14, UPnP/1.0, Portable SDK for UPnP devices/1.6.18
X-User-Agent: redsonic

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<s:Body>
<s:Fault>
<faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>UPnPError</faultstring>
<detail>
<UPnPError xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:control-1-0">
<errorCode>-111</errorCode>
<errorDescription>Invalid Action</errorDescription>
</UPnPError>
</detail>
</s:Fault>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Any ideas on how my request may be failing?

Comment: what about swapping `control/Layer3Forwarding` to `Layer3Forwarding/control` in the POST line? Thats how it looks like on my device.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I think my issue was that my SOAPACTION wasn't in quotes.  I seem to be getting responses in fiddler now.  Device Spy was a great help in tracking down the difference between my request and the a correctly formatted request.

Answer (score 4):

The UPnP [architecture spec](http://www.upnp.org/specs/arch/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v1.0-20080424.pdf) states that the format of action invocations is

```
POST path of control URL HTTP/1.1
HOST: host of control URL:port of control URL
CONTENT-LENGTH: bytes in body
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
SOAPACTION: "urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:serviceType:v#actionName"

<?xml version="1.0"?>
< s:Envelope
  xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <s:Body>
    <u:actionName xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:serviceType:v">
      <argumentName>in arg value</argumentName>
       other in args and their values go here, if any
    </u:actionName>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Your code deviates from this in a couple of ways:

- No newlines (`\r\n`) between HTTP headers (unless this is a formatting error in your question)
- The path in the `POST` header should not contain scheme, host or port. i.e. remove `http://192.168.1.4:52323`

You might also want to consider removing use of the `Expect` header.  There doesn't seem to be any benefit in adding it (you shouldn't expect to encounter any servers/proxies on a local network which support this header but can't cope with the overhead of a few hundred bytes of request body).  Conversely, its entirely possible you will encounter primitive HTTP servers which don't know how to process this header so reject the request.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I think there are new lines between the headers and that was just a formatting issue from copying it over from fiddler.  I edited the orginal post to show how I'm constructing the webRequest in C#.  I can try removing the expect header and fixing my POST value.